# "configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found" while installing Erlang

Tags: macos, openssl, erlang, kerberos

I am trying to install Erlang build 17 in my MAC and the below error shows up.

```
 * crypto         : OpenSSL is configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found
 * jinterface     : Java compiler disabled by user
 * odbc           : ODBC library - header check failed
 * ssh            : OpenSSL is configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found
 * ssl            : OpenSSL is configured for kerberos but no krb5.h found

DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION (See: /Users/xxx/.kerl/builds/17/otp_build_17.5.log)
 * documentation  : 
 *                  fop is missing.
 *                  Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.
```

My .kerlrc file contains the below options

```
CPPFLAGS="-march=native -mtune=native -O3 -g"
KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--with-ssl=/usr/bin --without-javac --enable-darwin-64bit --enable-shared-zlib
--enable-dynamic-ssl-lib --enable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads --enable-kernel-poll --with-wx"
KERL_DEFAULT_INSTALL_DIR="$KERL_BASE_DIR/installs"
```

Is anyone aware how to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="--disable-hipe --enable-smp-support --enable-threads --enable-kernel-poll
> --enable-darwin-62bit --with-ssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2h_1"
> ```

`--with-ssl="path/openssl"` option should fix it.

I also install javac by following this tutorial: [How to Install JDK 8 (on Windows, Mac & Ubuntu) and Get Started with Java Programming](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html).

Comment: `--enable-darwin-62bit`?

Comment: Thanks Kevin... It worked for me and the error is not there.

Answer (score 2):

Under Debian-based distributions `libkrb5-dev` needs to be installed as well:

```sh
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install libkrb5-dev
```